# How to set variable min and max value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, minimum

**ISSUE**

I am using a variable called `var addedToCart = 0;` . How to set a max and min value so that user cannot click more or less than the specified value and `var addedToCart`  will not store the out of range value?

#### I want

When `+ icon` clicked add value to `addedToCart`
When `- icon` clicked subtract value from `addedToCart` 
 *but within specified range*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use if statement

```
var MIN = 0;
...
if(value > MIN){
  setState({
    addedToCart--;
  })
}

...

if(value < MAX){
  setState({
    addedToCart++;
  })
}
```